# Azure Table Storage - calls timeout / never return from .NET 5 WebAPI running on Azure WebApp (Linux)

Tags: c#, azure, azure-table-storage, .net-5, orleans

Struggling with an issue here with our code, and looking to find ways to either solve it or better debug the situation.

We have a .NET 5 WebAPI project, which we are deploying to an Azure WebApp that is running Linux.

We have two "components" that access Azure Table Storage:

1. A repository class that wraps querying into Table Storage
2. An Orleans `IClusterClient`, which is using Table Storage for the cluster config (i.e. the `Build()`ing of the client will inspect Table Storage to get connection details to the Silo)

We have setup DI to inject both a wrapper to the `IClusterClient` and a generic `TableRepository<>` that the API controllers consume.

First, this is what we are doing to connect to Orleans:

```
var clientBuilder = new ClientBuilder()
    .Configure<ClusterOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.ClusterId = "clusterId";
        options.ServiceId = "serviceId";
    })
    .UseAzureStorageClustering(opts => opts.ConnectionString = "table_cnn_string");

var client = clientBuilder.Build(); // <-- this never returns, or times out
```

Right when we call `clientBuilder.Build()` the call just doesn't come back.  It **may** be timing out after 120 (or 180?) seconds.

Both this (the Orleans Client), and other code that is interacting with Table Storage, do so via the `Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table` nuget package (latest version - 1.0.8) has the same problem.

This snippet of code:

```
var client = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("cnn_str").CreateCloudTableClient();
var cloudTable = client.GetTableReference("ATable");
if (!await cloudTable.ExistsAsync()) // <-- never returns or times out after 120 seconds
{
    await cloudTable.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();
}
```

At the point where we call `cloudTable.ExistsAsync()` (or the non-async variant) we either never return or it times out after 120 seconds (I've definitely been able to track the timeout on this one).

Really struggling with this one, as when I run this locally on my Windows 10 dev box, all works 100% fine.

My scenarios are:

- Run the WebAPI from VS 2022 locally, everything works as expected
- Run the WebAPI from VS 2022, via WSL 2, everything works as expected
- Deploy to Azure WebApp, the **observation** is that these calls never return (but are probably timing out after 120 or so seconds)

So for example, we have a status API endpoint for monitoring that looks like this:

```
[ApiController]
public class StatusController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ILogger<StatusController> _logger;
    private readonly IClusterClient _clusterClient;


    public StatusController(ILogger<StatusController> logger,
            IClusterClient clusterClient)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _clusterClient = clusterClient;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<ApiStatusCheck>> GetStatus()
    {
        // ... bunch of other checks

        try
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("SILO CHECK");

            // there is no async version of this
            var checkGrain = await _clusterClient.GetGrain<IStatusCheck>(1); //<-- never returns
            _logger.LogInformation("SILO CHECK: got grain");
            details = await checkGrain.GetStatus();
            _logger.LogInformation($"SILO CHECK: got: {details}");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            details = ex.Message;
        }
   
        // ... more checks, then return a response
    }
```

Because I can't recreate this anywhere else other than an Azure WebApp, and I can't (as far as I understand) connect to it via the debugger (due to it running on Linux) I am struggling to understand:

- why this is happening
- why it works locally but not when deployed
- how to **really** diagnose the issue
- fix it (somehow)

The strange this on this, is that accessing Azure Blob Storage works fine.

Also, importantly, I cannot loose the use of the Orleans Client, and as that internally relies on `Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table`, simply switching to some other API is not on the cards (yet).

Any help appreciated.

Comment: is it only the orleans client having the problem?  The silo is ok?  What about the webapp itself making cosmos queries?

Comment: The silo operates fine and is accessible from other clients.  It's any table storage queries/access that is made, either by the webapi directly via the libraries, or the Orleans client by way of it accessing table storage via its internal work to access the cluster

Comment: @BrendanGreen have you had any luck with this one? I believe I'm seeing something very similar and am trying to fix

Comment: I think the issue we had was related to thread starvation.  We had both AI availability checks, plus Azure Front Door probes all hitting the instance even while it was warming up.  Mainly it was a reconfiguration of those external dependencies, and we've been stable ever since.